# How do we retrieve emails using phpMailer?

Tags: php, phpmailer

Here is the problem,
 i want to retrieve my mails from yahoo just like microsoft outlook using phpMailer and pop3 class.
I know about built-in imap in php but i want to use pop3 for this.

**Q1:** does phpMailer pop3 provide this ability?
**Q2:** can you give me a simple example how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

This class: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.pop3.php

is only for POP-Before-SMTP Authentication.

So it is not for downloading mails.